# OR-Tools Nurse scheduling problem with breaks and time intervals

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming

I have the nurse problem where only one shift is assigned to one employee on one day, but additionally I have these constraints:

1. One employee have to rest between 12 and 24 hours between
   shifts.
2. One employee can request to take days off between shifts
   (the first constraint is not forced then)

The shifs for the day are like these [start, end]:

```
Shift 0: rest
Shift 1: [8:00, 15:00]
Shift 2: [15:00, 22:00]
Shift 3: [8:00, 22:00]
Shift n: ...
```

I have tried modelling the problem with booleans as the example:

```
shifts = {}
for n in all_nurses:
    for d in all_days:
        for s in all_shifts:
            shifts[(n, d, s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%id%is%i' % (n, d, s))
```

But when I need to add constraints related to time and intervals, I find it very difficult to express the restrictions above.

Any suggestion? Could it be modelled in another way?

Comment: Please indicate when you crosspost.

Comment: crosspost: https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/4gkFDq8NTcs?hl=es

Comment: Have you see other solutions in GitHub? Example https://github.com/databill86/nurse-scheduling/blob/master/solve.py

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [the shift scheduling example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py)?

1. this constraints states that you cannot have a night shift followed by a morning shift.

this is encoded [in this constraint](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/86d4c543f717fa8716a9d66c25143660668bf825/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py#L328).

2. what is the 'days off between shift' rule? You always takes days off between shifts.

Comment: Hi, I mean holidays requested by user

Comment: No, what is the constraint ?

Comment: I have looked at the example, the problem is that I have to check hours, not days because I have to ensure that one employee have to rest between 12 and 24 hours between shifts. The rule for second is that if the user have requested a holiday, you cannot schedule a shift in that day for the user.

Comment: 1) You know each start and end time of each shift. So you know if shift a can follow shift b. 2) from the solver point of view, what is the difference between a day off an a rest day ?